# Beginner: mnist converted to jpeg model not accurate

Tags: keras, tensorflow, beginner

As a beginner I'm trying to understand the [Tensorflow quickstart tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) .
Basically the page gives you a series of buttons to click after wich you are told you achieved a 98% accuracy.

This is not very convincing, so I decided to expand on this by extracting the images of the mnist_train.csv file and train the model on these jpeg images directly instead of the somewhat cryptic `mnist.load_data()`.
My code for saving images was like this : `df=pd.read_csv('/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/mnist_train.csv', header=None) ; .... Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np.reshape(img[1:], (28,28)))).save(filename)` etc.

Now when I train the model directly on the jpegs using the same model and settings (`train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()` .. etc.) I get a much lower accuracy (93%).
Not only that but the model totally sucks when I feed it self made images. Every 9 is recognized as 8, every 7 as a 2 quite consistently.
The images from the dataset it is trained on  perform better as was to be expected..

Because I have no experience with this: can anybody point me in the right direction as to what I might expect from this example and also what I can do to debug or improve?
And why is the fit on the actual jpegs so much worse than the `mnist.load_data()` example?

example of a 9 from the mnist dataset:

[image: example of a 9 from the mnist dataset]

self made 9:

[image: self made 9]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: When providing new images to your model, have you normalized the pixel values as is done for the training data in the linked tutorial?

Comment: @Oxbowerce Great, Thanks! I added a  'tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),'  in the model and it works like in the example. It still doesn't recognize my own images as well as I would expect but that can have several causes. I think this is how it's supposed to function.